# Consequences to manually adding a entry to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall`

Tags: windows-registry, windows-server-2016

We have an application, lets call it 'App A', that when you run it checks the registry to see if another app, lets call it 'App B', is installed. It does this by searching `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall` for any entry with a `DisplayName` equal to 'App B'.

Now, App A doesn't actually need App B to run correctly and we've lost the ability to install App B on our systems. So my question is...

Are there any consequences to creating a registry entry at `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\App A` with the appropriate display name? I think this could be accomplished with a *.reg file containing the following...

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\App 1]
"DisplayName"="App 1"
```

Comment: For one you will likely have strange issues if you decide to install the original app again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can certainly do that to fake an application is installed.

Given the information here:
https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040709-00/?p=38493
the only mandated values when adding an entry are DisplayName and the UninstallPath.

You can also set the SystemComponent DWORD value to hide the application from the list of applications in Programs and Features if needed.  So the following will be fine:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\App 1]
"DisplayName"="App 1"
"UninstallPath"="C:\\fake.exe"
"SystemComponent"=dword:00000001
```